# Automatically Update Values in Database from DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I'm currently working on a project using MySql in combination with C#.
The Data for the DataGridView is provided by a join from multiple tables in the DB. To show the data I use the following, working, code:

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(
            " SELECT" +
            " l.lot AS Lot, "+
            " m.comment AS Bemerkungen," +
            ... (multiple columns from different tables) ...
            " FROM m " +
            " JOIN m2p ON m.m2p_id = m2p.id" +
            ... (more joins) ...
            , this._mySqlConnection);
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
adapter.Fill(data);
```

Now the user of the GUI is allowed to modify a certain column (the "comment" column). So I assigned an eventHandler to the `CellEndEdit` event and when the user modified the allowed column the `adapter.Update(data)` is called. Now this doesn't perform the correct action.

To define my updatecommand I used the following code:

```
adapter.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(
                " UPDATE m" +
                " JOIN  l ON m.l_id = l.id" +
                " SET m.comment = @comment" +
                " WHERE l.lot = @lot"
                , this._mySqlConnection);
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@comment", MySqlDbType.Text, 256, "Bemerkungen");
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@lot", MySqlDbType.Text, 256, "Lot");
```

Could you explain me how I fix my code to automatically Update the database?

EDIT:
added further source code:

```
private MySqlDataAdapter warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter, kundenMySqlDataAdapter;
private DataTable warenlagerData, kundenData;
private DataGridView warenlagerGridView;

private void updateWarenlagerView(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter.Update(warenlagerData);
}

private void initialzeFields() {
            warenlagerGridView.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.updateWarenlagerView);
            warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            warenlagerData = new DataTable();
            }

private void initializeWarenlagerView() {
            warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(
                " SELECT" +
                " c.name AS Ursprung, " +
                " m2p.art_nr AS ArtNr," +
                " m.delivery_date AS Eingangsdatum," +
                " CONCAT(FORMAT(m.delivery_amount / 100, 2), 'kg') AS Eingangsmenge, " +
                " l.lot AS Lot," +
                " m.quality AS Qualität," +
                " m.comment AS Bemerkungen," +
                " CONCAT(m.units, 'kg') AS Units," +
                " CONCAT(FORMAT(s.amount / 100, 2), 'kg') AS Lagermenge, " +
                " FORMAT(m.base_price / 100, 2) AS Einkaufspreis," +
                " FORMAT(s.amount/10000 * m.base_price, 2) AS Wert" +
                " FROM mushrooms AS m " +
                " JOIN mushroom2path AS m2p ON m.mushroom2path_id = m2p.id" +
                " JOIN countries AS c ON m.origin_id = c.id" +
                " JOIN lots AS l ON m.lot_id = l.id" +
                " JOIN stock AS s ON s.mushrooms_id = m.id"
                , this._mySqlConnection);
            warenlagerGridView.DataSource = warenlagerData;
            warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter.Fill(warenlagerData);
            warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand(
                " UPDATE mushrooms AS m" +
                " JOIN lots AS l ON m.lot_id = l.id" +
                " SET m.comment = @comment" +
                " WHERE l.lot = @lot"
                , this._mySqlConnection);
            warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@comment", MySqlDbType.Text, 256, "Bemerkungen");
            warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@lot", MySqlDbType.Text, 256, "Lot");
        }
```

This is the whole code concerning this problem. I'm 100% sure the `adapter.Update(data)` method is called (debugging). And the data which is passed to the `adapter.Update()` method contains the new data.

Comment: What happens when you run this query, then?

Comment: Nothing happens to the database... I know (through debugging) the `adapter.Update(data)` method is called and data contains the new value. But the database still has the old value

Comment: cant you put simply `GridView1.DataBind();` at the end of your code? `GridView1` replaced by your reader

Comment: @DiederikEEn `GridView1.DataBind()` is only needed in webForms not in winForms. So it doesn't make any difference in this case

Comment: What happen when you run your SQL command directly on database with hardcoced `@coment` and `@lot` variables ?

Comment: @MartinPerry it works without any problems. If needed I can post more of my code if that could help.

Comment: @LukasHäfliger I am not sure, but where are you calling some kind of commit on adapter ?

Comment: @MartinPerry as far as I read everything is done in the `adapter.Update(data)` method. This will read the changes from the data  object and call the UpdateCommand with the new vlues from the data objevt. If I'm wrong please corret me

Comment: @LukasHäfliger Method CellEndEdit is called properly (I mean if you debug code, that cou reach the inside of method) ? Could you post complete code...

Comment: @MartinPerry I added the whole source code concerning this problem. Just have a look at my initial post. The CellEndEdit is really called when I'm finished editing the cell and I want to update the database

Comment: Can someone explain to me how the UpdateCommand parameter values are assigned?

Comment: What if you just put it in a try catch and post the exception? maybe something happens.

Comment: See my update in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your update statement is incorrect. It should be:

```
"UPDATE m FROM mushrooms m JOIN lots l ON m.lot_id = l.id SET m.comment = @comment WHERE l.lot = @lot"
```

Comment: No your MySql command is not a valid MySql command. "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM mushrooms m JOIN lots l ON m.lot_id = l.id SET m.comment = 'Test' WH' at line 1"

Comment: and I checked my MySql Command. It is correct when I call it from the console

Comment: Oh! It's MySQL?? I thought its T-Sql (Sql Server).

Comment: Yes I stated this in the initial post

Comment: You dont need quotes around parameters :)

Answer (score 3):

Please try this update query it works.

```
UPDATE mushrooms 
SET comment = @comment
WHERE 
l_id=(select id from l where lot=@lot)
```

Comment: You should try to use Joins rather than sub queries. It's better practice.

Comment: this command is equivalent to my query and doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to execute the warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand?
You are just setting the command and the parameters but not executing it.

What I see is that you are calling the update when the info is updated, but your update command is not loaded.
You just call `updateWarenlagerView` when you update the row, but where are you calling `initialzeFields`?

Or am I missing code?

Comment: no because I added an eventhandler which calls `adapter.Update()` (see complete code)

Comment: `private void updateWarenlagerView(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            warenlagerMySqlDataAdapter.Update(warenlagerData);
}` fourth line of code

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your update code from the `CellEndEdit` event to the `CellValueChanged` event and see if this works.

Comment: thanks but that didn't help... I know the CellEndEdit event is called. I verified this several times

Comment: Maybe view the actual query that is run in MySQL, just to be sure the `datasource` you are using contains the correct updated comment field

Answer (score 0):

Try this example out:

```
public void UpdateAllFromDgv(DataGridView dataGridView1)
{
    string query = "Update List set ColumnName1=@Value1" +
        ",ColumnName2=@Value2" +
        ",ColumnName3=@Value3" +
        ",ColumnName4=@Value4" +
        ",ColumnName5=@Value5" +
        ",ColumnName6=@Value6  where ColumnName0=@Value0";
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value0", row.Cells[0].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", row.Cells[1].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", row.Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value3", row.Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value4", row.Cells[4].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value5", row.Cells[5].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value6", row.Cells[6].Value);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataGridView1.ResetBindings();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException MsE)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(MsE.Message.ToString());

    }
}
```